# How to get exact amount of RAM httpd process uses for a PHP script?

Tags: php, apache

I want to run a PHP script and find out exactly how much RAM the httpd process that is running it is using. I have run a trace on the script with xdebug that shows me the script is using 3.9M. However when I run `top`, I see a lot of processes using 115M and more.

I'm not sure exactly what scripts are using how much RAM. I have access to the Apache status page, which doesn't show me the RAM the processes are using.

How can I run a PHP script and see exactly how much RAM the resulting httpd process is using?

Comment: Use `memory_get_usage` and `memory_get_peak_usage` to get peak use of memory

Comment: `ps` output isn't useful, since php-in-apache will show the entire apache child's memory usage, and much of that will be shared with other children.

Comment: I have used the memory functions but it seems like the httpd processes take a lot more memory then php says it's using. Should the php memory functions = the process ram useage? Or is there other stuff going on in the process that uses some kind of overhead?